# Select one class only within SCSS

Tags: sass

I am using the following code to apply styles to all classes nested within the `.twitter-` class:

```
    a[class^="twitter-"] {
        margin-right: 5px;
        opacity: .8;

        &:before {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        &:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

There are a few classes under twitter for example: `.twitter-reply`, `.twitter-retweet` as well as `.twitter-fav`.

I want a 5px right margin to apply to all `twitter-*` classes, with the exception of `.twitter-fav` - see example below:

```
<div class="twitter-reply">Example</div>
<div class="twitter-retweet">Example</div>
<div class="twitter-fav">Example</div>
```

I have tried researching it but cannot find the correct terms.

Comment: Please provide some example HTML code we can work with.

Comment: Please provide an example of the CSS output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this problem by using last-child instead as per the example below:

```
a[class^="twitter-"] {
        margin-right: 5px;

        &:before {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        &:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        &:last-child{
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this would be to take advantage of `:not()`.

```
a[class^="twitter-"] {
  // your other styles

  &:not(.twitter-fav) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

This will apply `margin-right: 5px;` to all twitter links except the `-fav`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put some margin between elements with `.twitter-` class but your are not sure which one is the last element, you could try using this:

```
[class^=twitter-"] {
    & + a[class^=twitter-"] {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

the plus symbol select the element right after the previous selector

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood you want to *nest* multiple classes, right?
So, an element with the class of `.twitter-fav` *inside* your `.twitter-*` class should receive an extra portion of styling, right?

If so:

```
a[class^="twitter-"] {
  .twitter-fav {
    // Your styling
  }
  margin-right: 5px;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

This will affect all elements like so:

```
<div class="twitter-whatever">
  <div class="twitter-fav">
  </div>
</div>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that's what's being asked here at all.  It sounds like the OP wants to take advantage of nesting in a way that would give them styles for `a[class^="twitter-"]` and `a.twitter-fav`.